# Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_5: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, vgg-net

I am trying to fine-tune VGG16 neural network, here is the code:

```
vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top="false", input_shape=(224,224,3))
model = Sequential()
model.add(vgg16_model)
#add fully connected layer:
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

I am getting this error:

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in
>
> 2 model.add(vgg16_model)
>
> 3 #add fully connected layer:
>
> ----> 4 model.add(Flatten())
>
> 5 model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
>
> 6 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
>   179                 self.inputs = network.get_source_inputs(self.outputs[0])
>
> 180         elif self.outputs:
>
> --> 181             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>
> 182             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
>
> 183                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>
> 412                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
>
> 413                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
>
> --> 414                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
>
> 415
>
> 416                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
>
> 325                                      self.name + ': expected min_ndim=' +
>
> 326                                      str(spec.min_ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
>
> --> 327                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
>
> 328             # Check dtype.
>
> 329             if spec.dtype is not None:
>
> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_5: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

I tried many suggested solutions but none of them could solve my problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you want to flatten the output? It's not a 2D images that VGG16 outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In officially [keras](https://keras.io/applications/) webpage, on

> Fine-tune InceptionV3 on a new set of classes

```
from keras.models import Model
vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top="false", input_shape=(224,224,3))
x = vgg16_model.output
x=Flatten()(x)
x=Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions=Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

You have an error in `include_top="false"`, this causes you the error message. Try:

```
vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: You are right. I have updated my answer, it should run fine now.

Comment: Thanks! It runs fine now.

Comment: include_top=False, not "false"